# Права на редактирование своего магазина

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Использую [laravel-admin](https://laravel-admin.org/) при добавлении магазина хочу чтобы каждый редактировал свой магазин.

При отображении сделал так чтобы отображались только их магазины но когда к примеру user12 переходит по ссылке на редактирование поста gameshop/main/stores/8/edit который был создал admin пользователь user12 имеет доступ на редактирование удалени...

Как сделать чтобы каждый пользователь мог редактировать только свой магазин ?
ShopsController:
<?php

```
namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Models\Shops;
use App\Models\Games;
use Encore\Admin\Controllers\AdminController;
use Encore\Admin\Form;
use Encore\Admin\Facades\Admin;
use Encore\Admin\Grid;
use Encore\Admin\Show;
use App\Models\User;
use Request;

use DB;
class ShopsController extends AdminController
{
    /**
     * Title for current resource.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title = 'Магазины';

    /**
     * Make a grid builder.
     *
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new Shops());
        if(!Admin::user()->isAdministrator())
        $grid->model()->where('user_id', Admin::user()->id);

        $grid->column('id', __('ID'));
        if(Admin::user()->isAdministrator())
        {
            $grid->column('user_id', trans('admin.user_name'))->display(function ($userid) {
            return Admin::user()->find($userid)->username;
        })->label();
        }
        $grid->column('game', trans('admin.game'))->display(function ($gameid) {
            return Games::find($gameid)->name;
        })->label();

        $grid->column('shop_name', trans('admin.shop_name'))->editable();
        $grid->column('created_at', __('Created at'));
        $grid->disableExport();
        $grid->actions(function (Grid\Displayers\Actions $actions) {
            $actions->disableView();
        });
        return $grid;
    }

    /**
     * Make a show builder.
     *
     * @param mixed $id
     * @return Show
     */
    protected function detail($id)
    {
        $show = new Show(Shops::findOrFail($id));

        $show->field('id', __('ID'));
        $show->field('game', trans('admin.game'))->as(function ($gameid) {
            return Games::find($gameid)->name;
        })->label();
        $show->field('shop_name', trans('admin.shop_name'));
        $show->field('created_at', __('Created at'));
        return $show;
    }

    /**
     * Make a form builder.
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    protected function form()
    {
        $form = new Form(new Shops());
        $usershops = DB::table('shops')->where('user_id',Admin::user()->id)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $form->hidden('user_id')->default(Admin::user()->id);
        $form->select('game', trans('admin.game'))->options(function () {
        $games = Games::where('active', 1)->get();
        $games_all = [];
        foreach($games as $game)
        {
            $games_all += [$game->id => $game->name];
        }
        return $games_all;
        });
        $form->text('shop_name', trans('admin.shop_name'));
        return $form;
    }
}
```

routers.php

```
$router->resource('stores', ShopsController::class);
```

База данные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак, так как в ней разделения на права и их проверки для каждого пользователя. Есть только "Админ" роль или "Не-Админ".

Comment: Если создавать роль под каждого автора и доступ к страницам думаю возможно

Comment: Этот проект не предназначается для многопользовательской среды, думаю вам лучше посмотреть в сторону [tenancy](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) либо расширения от [spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается таким образом
При каждой регистрации пользователя выдаем ему отдельную пермиссию(доступ) http_path
Добавляя его в admin_premissions
Далее при каждом создании магазина выдаем ему доступ только к своим магазинам /store/3
/store/4

А также выдаем роль котором стандартные пермиссии
/store/create
/main/
...

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте проверку где id владельца магазина ==  auth()->id();